# Separate public and edit-mode versions of database record

Tags: database-design, cakephp, primary-key, multiple-columns

How would I best implement an edit-mode for a database record?

The record (for example a blog post) needs to have a public version visible on the website while the edit-mode version is being edited, previewed, re-edited, etc.

So far, I have two solutions in mind:

1. Use a multi-column primary key, with the ID and the mode.
2. Use separate tables for each mode, and copy between them.

I can't be the first one to need this feature.

How is this usually done? Does it have a name?

I use CakePHP which doesn't explicitly support multi-column keys, but I don't think it matters to my situation, as I won't actually have multiple rows with the same ID after the user is done editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the database is concerned, you don't need an edit mode. *Especially* over the web--http is an unreliable transport protocol.

If your user interface allows editing, then you just edit and (I presume) click a button, and code "behind" the button eventually sends the changed data back to the database as an UPDATE statement. If the UPDATE statement is formed correctly, and if the editor and application have sufficient permissions, the UPDATE will succeed, and the data will be changed.

Anyone who reads that particular row before the UPDDATE will see the old version; anyone who reads it after the UPDATE will see the new version. (Ignoring the effect of possible caching.)

Comment: In the end, this seemed to be the simplest solution. I just post the data back and forth between pages by generating hidden forms on the preview-page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a versioning system or the ability to create a post and not make it live until it is approved by an admin. I do not think this is native to cakePHP but what you could do is,

Copy the edit function in the controller->duplicate->rename then do the same for the edit view, then create a new db table called edits. Also create a dropdown box for "save" or "publish"

Then when the submit button is pressed you can decide which db table the post will populate by viewing the data in $this->data.

I think this would be the easiest way since duplicating the edit function you will not have to worry about sending the id of the post to the function, cake will do it automatically. so your id's for the posts table and the edits table should match up.